# How to set blank date on jquery datepicker in rails (3.1.0) ajax?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

In our rails 3.1.0 app, ajax is used to load a view with jquery datepicker for return_date. The js code for return_date in application.js is:

```
// for AJAX
$(function() {
   $("#test_sample_return_date").live('click', function() {
        $(this).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', showOn:'focus' }).focus();
    });   
});
```

With this implementation, datepicker loads when the view is loaded ajax way. However '0001/1/1' is always set as default in return_date instead of a blank as needed. Options, such as currentText, defaultDate for datepicker did not work. `$(this).removeAttr('value')` was used. However the value attribute was only removed after user clicks return_date field first which loads '0001/1/1' initially.

Any thoughts about how to set blank for datepicker in rails ajax? Thanks so much.

UPDATE:

Here is the one line of rails simple_form code to load the return_date:

```
  <%= f.input :return_date, :label => "Return Date： ", :as => :string %>
```

return_date is a date field. :as option loads return_date in a text box as a string instead of a date. When clicking the return_date box, the datepicker is fired up and displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Your method of `$(this).removeAttr('value')` should work, but you're calling `datepicker` on the click function.
I would do this on `$(document).ready()` instead.
Here's an example:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#test_sample_return_date").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', showOn:'focus' }).focus().val('');
});
```

I just added `.val('')` to the end, but you could alternatively do:

```
$("#test_sample_return_date").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', showOn:'focus' }).focus().removeAttr('value')
```

#### Edit:

I just did a test and found out that `.val('')` doesn't actually remove the value. `.removeAttr('value')` seems to do the trick though!

Comment: Tried both .val() and .removeAttr('value') and did not work. The '0001/1/1' still loads. $(function) used for $(document).ready(function() {} )

Comment: Tried .removeAttr('value') again and it did not work. focus() may hold the field and only release after click. Need to find a way to initiate a blank date in the field.

Comment: Can you post your code on how you're retrieving that value? Maybe you're looking at a variable that was set to a new Date object? I'm not too familiar with rails, but I might be able to spot something. The actual value of the textbox itself is a zero length string after calling '.removeAttr("value")', so the front end code is working as intended.

Comment: IanW, just updated the post to show the rails view code. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I would imagine the problem is that you're going from a Date object to a String. I'm trying to figure out exactly what you're trying to accomplish. Is there a function somewhere that does an Ajax call to set the value of that textbox? Either way, you should call the .datepicker() function in your $(document).ready() as that only needs to be done once, not every time the user clicks it.

Comment: $(this).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', showOn:'focus' }).removeAttr('value').focus(); does the trick. I just put the removeAttr before focus. It removes the value attribute first before gets focus. thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

set showOn option to 'button'

```
$("#test_sample_return_date").datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', showOn:'button' })
```